# Images won't show when open page by clicking in a link

Tags: jquery, html, bxslider

[Here](http://wearesoda.com/jjlustres/galeria/) is my page.

At the bottom of it there is a image list (bx-slider) that won't appear when you click in the link (galeria at the menu), but when you press F5 it loads.

Does anyone have any idea of why it does weird behavior ?

EDIT: Here is a video explaining what I said:
http://wearesoda.com/development/2012-08-28_1059.swf

Comment: Try to clear your cache -- it works fine for me: http://screencast.com/t/3Igbq4XXaXsh If clearing your cache doesn't help, try to find what exact steps you can follow to reproduce the problem. Or... is the failure happening in a specific browser? I was using Firefox 14.0.1 there.

Comment: by clicking the link, it goes to another page. how do you handle that page?

Comment: I've added a video explaining the problem

Answer (score 0):

i found width problem in your slider, that problem occurs after clicking on link also... it show **width 20px** while that not shows

put this in your CSS, and check

```
.bx-window{
  width:565px !important;
}
```

Image loading and cache problem
preload all images and check....